# Best practices for organizing and managing Django email templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates, email-templates, django-email

I'm building an app with over 20 different email notifications and I want to provide a nice way for the product team to verify the copy for each of these emails. I'm considering building two views, one to list all the email templates and another to display their content. I did some googling and have not yet found a better approach. Does there exist a better method for managing email templates in Django?

Comment: None that so far. Only way is to manage it in the templates html and create a test view to render it for the product team. `/email?name=welcome` and you can create a static page with list of templates.

Comment: Yeah, that's essentially what I'm doing now.

Comment: You can also answer your own question.